# I can't get the last column line in my table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, cline

```
\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{1-4}
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Player 1} \\ \cline{1-4}
& & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ \\
\cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{Player 2} & $\alpha$ & $0,0$ & $3,-1$\\
\cline{2-4}
& $\beta$ & $-1,3$ & $0,0$ \\
\cline{1-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

What mistake am I making?

[image: Output]

Also I would like to remove the left vertical line, left of Player 1, from the 1st row only. 
How should I go about doing this?

Comment: However, I would urge you to reconsider the vertical lines in your table. Try opening the table up and use the [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en) package to help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: adeetyaTabular]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Player 1} \\ \cline{3-4}
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}    & $\alpha$                                     & $\beta$ \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Player 2} & $\alpha$                                     & $0,0$      & $3,-1$\\
        & $\beta$                                      & $-1,3$     & $0,0$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Player 1}` to add the line to the right and `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` in the previous cell to remove the one on the left.

Comment: Right.  But vertical lines should be avoided in tables whenever possible.

Comment: @JPi but the question was not about document style (and it's not clear that general advice about formal data tables applies to a generic tableau setting such as this)

Comment: I agree, I value your answer (+1), and don't like it when questions are criticized without an answer.  But given that you have provided an answer, it doesn't hurt....